# Chrome and opera leaves empty space on top because of li padding

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

I'm working on a homepage with fullpage slider.
At firefox everything went right!
At Chrome and Opera, I have an empty space on the top of the page.

I noticed that all the space is from the menu padding (li), when I turn it to 0 the space is getting shorter but is not leaving.

Here is my html

```
 <ul id="connect">
    <li>
    logo
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="menu">
    <li>menu1</li>
    <li>menu2</li>
    <li>menu3</li>
    <li>menu4</li>
</ul>
```

And my css is

```
#connect {
z-index: 10;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
margin-left: 90px;
padding: 20px;
}


#menu {
z-index: 10;
float: right;
margin: 0;
font-size:12px;
list-style: none;
position:relative;
top:30px;
right:20px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

li {

    display:block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Could someone help?

Comment: http://sscce.org/ on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: did you try reducing the `top: 30px` value assigned to the `#menu` element? a link to the live website where this problem can be seen will be very helpful in order to figure out the issue which you're facing.

Comment: A link to your website is more useful or I can accept a jsfiddle

Comment: Here is the url http://www.headroom-studios.com/,
the top: 30px is only the menu placement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd re-write your code like this so it's more simple and semantic: http://jsfiddle.net/kc4umn1c/

Whenever you use "position: fixed" you should also specify your X/Y coordinates ("left/right" in this case). I've added the styles below.

Also, look into using a reset.css file to make all of your styles fit nicely between browsers. (google html5 boiler plate, they have a good one.)

Good luck!

**HTML**

```
    <header class="header">
        <h1 class="logo">logo</h1>

        <nav class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>menu1</li>
                <li>menu2</li>
                <li>menu3</li>
                <li>menu4</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

**CSS**

```
    * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

    .header {     
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: black;
        z-index: 1;
        padding: 20px;
        color: white; 
    }

    .logo { 
        float: left; 
        display: inline-block; 
    }

    .menu {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
    }

    .menu ul {
        list-style: none;
    }

    .menu ul li {
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!!! I wonder why I didn't try header section from the beginning. Thanks MrRioku.